# Need help understanding click behavior in my JavaScript toggle function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This should be simple, but I don't understand why it isn't working as expected. I have a search bar that, by default, has a class of "search-bar--hidden," which applies a property of "display: none." A class of "search-bar--visible" applies "display: flex."

I have a function to toggle those classes.

In my HTML, I have:

```
<div class="site-head__icn-search" onclick="toggleSearch()">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

And in my JavaScript I have:

```
function toggleSearch() {
    var searchBar = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    var searchInput = document.getElementById("search-bar-input");

    if (searchBar.classList.contains("search-bar--hidden")) {
        searchBar.classList.remove("search-bar--hidden");
        searchBar.classList.add("search-bar--visible");
        searchInput.focus();
    } else {
        searchBar.classList.remove("search-bar--visible");
        searchBar.classList.add("search-bar--hidden");
        searchInput.blur();
    }
}
```

When I click on the search icon, the search box does appear as expected. And when I click it again, it disappears....but when I release that second click, it appears again. It's almost like the browser is detecting an additional click somehow.

You can see all of this in action at http://www.christmaspast.media

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: On your website there is a click handler on the `i` element as well.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, even though that is not in my HTML. I think the Font Awesome library I use adds that automatically. I wonder if that's part of the issue. Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: @BrianO'Neill Use `addEvenetListener` in your script instead. Inline event handlers are a bad practice anyway.

Comment: Also, why are you using two classes when you can use only one. Just git rid of one of them (preferably `search-bar--visible`) and use only the other. Add that `display: flex` as default to `#search-bar`.

Comment: Are you still facing that problem? I've just taken a look at your website and the button doesn't have the event attached to it at all. I added it to it using the console and it worked as expected, are you sure you are adding it right?

Comment: Yes, still having the issue. I looked in the console and see an error saying cannot addEventListener to null. I thought it might be because I didn't correctly type the ID of the DOM element in my addEventListener, but it's exactly the same. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Just add `document.getElementById("search-icon").addEventListener("click", toggleSearch);` to [**your script**](http://christmaspast.media/wp-content/themes/cpm-theme/js/scripts.min.js?ver=1.0) and it should work

Comment: @BrianO'Neill That's because your code is executed before the DOM is constructed.

Comment: But that is exactly what I did.

Comment: Just wrap that in a DOMContentLoaded event listener will do: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  /* add code here */ });`

Comment: Tested this on Chrome and Firefox, BTW.

Comment: Also you are using jQuery, so why not do the whole thing in jQuery?

Comment: I'm actually not using jQuery. It's a Wordpress theme, so jQuery is there by default. Does it make a difference either way?

Comment: @BrianO'Neill No, no difference at all. It will just make things shorter, i.e. wrapping code in `$(function() { ... })` instead of `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { ... });` and more shortening elsewhere too

Comment: @IbrahimMahrir, I just re-did the code in jQuery. Was not working at first, until I did this with my code: function toggleSearch(e) {e.preventDefault(); // rest of code goes here}

Comment: But it works now! thanks for all your help! much appreciated :-)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function toggleSearch(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('site-head__icn-search') && 
  !e.target.closest('.site-head__icn-search').classList.contains('site- 
  head__icn-search'))
      return false;

var searchBar = document.getElementById("search-bar");
var searchInput = document.getElementById("search-bar-input");

if (searchBar.classList.contains("search-bar--hidden")) {
    searchBar.classList.remove("search-bar--hidden");
    searchBar.classList.add("search-bar--visible");
    searchInput.focus();
} else {
    searchBar.classList.remove("search-bar--visible");
    searchBar.classList.add("search-bar--hidden");
    searchInput.blur();
}

}

<div class="site-head__icn-search" onclick="toggleSearch(event)">
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>
```

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is already stated in [**this comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221169/need-help-understanding-click-behavior-in-my-javascript-toggle-function#comment87459813_50221169): that he have two event listeners, one on the `<div>` and one on its child `<i>` element

Comment: Okey, so try finding closest '.site-head__icn-search'

Comment: I've updated the HTML, CSS, and JS. Everything is now registered as a click event with addEventListener. The "onclick" no longer appears in the HTML anywhere. And I have a single CSS modifier of "search-bar--hidden," rather than one for hidden and one for visible. Still getting the same behavior. http://www.christmaspast.media